# command+click does not work in some widget for moving to that widget file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am facing a problem in android studio,

command+ click is used to go to the selected widget file..

Its working in all files but not working with some widgets only

what can be the issue?

Comment: Are those widgets imported in the file? Also, please include the code for the widgets/files for better understanding of the problem.